# Jsf share information for all users

Tags: jsf, session

I have a system using jsf and prime faces.

I would like to:

On the homepage show all logged users name and total number of them in real time.

On each page show the same but related to each specific page. I want the user to know who is looking at the same page at the same time.

The scope needs to be view because some pages have sensitive information.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make an `@ApplicationScoped` bean store all that info you want to share across the users. Then, you can have the info relative to what is private for user in `@ViewScoped`. Remember you can refer both of them from the same view.

Having said that, the main challenge is to know when the user has finished the session in some way. From JSF point of view I understand it's impossible to know, so the trick is going one step further and play with [`HttpSessionBindingListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionBindingListener.html) as it's explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2085731/1199132).

Let's provide a basic implementation of the `@ApplicationScoped` bean (supposing you are using JSF 2 and EL 2.2, which allows you passing params to server methods):

```
@ManagedBean
@ApplicationScoped
public class GeneralInfo{

    List<UserBean> onlineUsers;

    //Getters and setters

    public int numberUsersWathingThis(String viewId){
        int result = 0;
        for (UserBean ub : onlineUsers){
            if (ub.getCurrentViewId().equals("viewId")){
                result++;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

Here you could store a list of users that are actually online. Supposing each user has a `String` property **which specifies the displayed current view**, we would need a simple iteration to retrieve how many users are currently in the specified view id.

Then let's supose you have a `@SessionScoped` bean which keeps also the current logged in user. That bean is created when HttpSession begins and creates the current UserBean when user logs in. `UserBean` will find the `GeneralInfo` bean and inject itself into it.

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class SessionBean{

    UserBean userBean;

    //Create your UserBean when user logs into the application

    public void setCurrentPage(String currentViewId){
        userBean.setCurrentViewId(currentViewId);
    }

}
```

And the implementation of `UserBean`, which needs to implement `HttpSessionBindingListener` in order to be notified before it's removed from the [`HttpSession`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html). If you take a look, this notification will trigger a `UserBean#valueUnbound` method call, from which the bean is removed by itself from the `@ApplicationScoped` managed bean. This allows `GeneralInfo` bean to know **what users are actually online**.

```
public class UserBean implements HttpSessionBindingListener{

    @ManagedProperty(value="#{generalInfo}")
    GeneralInfo generalInfo;

    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct(){
        generalInfo.addUser(this);
    }

    @Override
    void valueUnbound(HttpSessionBindingEvent event){
        generalInfo.removeUser(this);
    }

    //Getter and Setters

}
```

After that, as a last challenge, we want to know what the current user is watching. An easy way to solve that is to use the `@ViewScoped` bean which manages the current view to update the `UserBean` which is stored in the `@SessionScoped` bean. So let's bring access the current `@ViewScoped` bean to that and update what the user is seeing:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Page1Info{

    @ManagedProperty(value="#{sessionBean}")
    SessionBean sessionBean;

    public void initialize(ComponentSystemEvent event){
        sessionBean.setCurrentPage("page1.xhtml");
    }

}
```

That `page1Info#initialize` method is called as a [`preRenderView`](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-prerenderviewevent-example/) event (use `f:viewAction` for JSF 2.2+). So at the end there will be some kind of that view:

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:event type="preRenderView"
        listener="#{page1Info.initialize}" />
</f:metadata>
<h:outputText value="There are #{fn:length(generalInfo.onlineUsers)} users online" />
<h:outputText value="There are #{numberUsersWathingThis("page1.xhtml")} users watching this" />
```

Comment: How about users opening several pages in multiple browser tabs in same or even different sessions? ;) Kudos for the investigation effort and offering a kickoff example anyway.

Comment: That would be something that could be managed using hidden input fields for example? Can't think in other way right now. Anyway, thanks for your greetings and feel free to edit it, this answer is learnt from your posts!

Comment: @Xtreme That is a very elaborated and thoughtful answer. My regards as well.

Comment: You're welcome! Igor, remember you can mark it as the accepted answer if you consider it clicking on the checkmark (✓) at the left of the answer.